# Is there a general rule for the prefixation of "un-" and "de-" to words?

Tags: differences, prefixes, un-de, morphological-domains, productive-affixes

Given the different questions we have seen about the prefixes "de-" and "un-", I have grown curious if there is a overarching rule for terms that need undoing.

- [“Unselect” or “Deselect”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18465/unselect-or-deselect)
- [“Unregister” vs “Deregister”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25931/unregister-vs-deregister)

For actions taken that need to be revoked or reversed, which prefix is preferred? Is there a distinction created by the underlying terms? Is it purely a usage issue where the one most used is the one to use? Do "un-" and "de-" actually have different meanings such that both could help determine which is most appropriate?

Comment: Lady MacB: "desex me here?" Hmmm.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Some prescriptive grammarians would argue that the *de-* prefix should be used on verbs and *un-* should be used on adjectives.

So, you *deregister* something and it becomes *unregistered*, or you *deselect* something and it is now *unselected*.

The logic behind this is probably because *de-* only attaches to verbs to give the notion of reversal, so for the sake of order/non-redundancy/etc. you'd want *un-* to occupy the other domain: yielding the opposite meaning of an adjective it attaches to, and nothing else.

However, it has never really worked this way; the prefix redundancy among verbs is there, and it is very unlikely to disappear.  Note that, most of the time, you can't just use whichever one you want — usually there is one preferred form.  But whether it is *un-* or *de-* is something that varies on a word-by-word basis.

FumbleFingers mentioned something else in comments that is worth mentioning: *un-* seems to be *much* more widespread, even in the verbal realm, in the production of new words in the past few decades.

Comment: Until recently "un-" as a *verbal* prefix was quite limited in the class of verbs it would attach to: those of closing, fastening, wrapping only (with rare exceptions like "unsay"). It was still productive, but only within that semantic field. Recently, particularly in the computer world, it has become more productive, probably as backformations from participles with "un-".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Excellent summary of both the position and the rationale. But I suspect the *deselect/unselected* pairing may actually become significantly *less* 'preferred' over time, simply because modern computer screens force us to juxtapose the two words far more often than we used to. People will opt for one prefix over the other in both forms. Whatever - I doubt we'll see much of a rise in the use of *decheck* paired with *unchecked* in the coming years.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I've heard this said, but I wonder how true this actually is — I think this is another prescriptive attempt to retain neat categories for these prefixes in spite of contrary evidence. Just looking through the OED for verbs occurring pre-20th century that begin with *un-*, I see lots of words: *unalchemy* (1661), *unanchor* (1648), *unappoint* (1682), *unarm* (1470), *unassure* (1643), *unavail* (1866), *unbalast* (1769), *unbaptize* (1611), *unbeautify* (1570), *unbed* (1611).  This is just a selection from among the first few pages of the 1300 results.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree with your suspicion — I don't think the prescriptivist's rationale for wanting a dichotomy has much impact on what will happen in the language, and it does seem like *un-* is much more productive these days.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Productive? It's positively fecund! Actually, I quite like the way we all routinely talk about the **undo** function nowadays.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, *productive* being the technical linguistic term for the phenomenon... :)

Comment: Yeah I did know that. Just trying to drag you academic guys down to my level :-)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: maybe you're right about the productiveness of "un-" with verbs, but I'm dubious. I'm aware of the semantic restriction because I read about it in Whorf (one of his examples of "cryptotypes") not because I have ever been taught it. "Unsay" sounds distinctly odd to me. I agree that it has become much more productive recently.

Comment: @ColinFine: I would posit that to "de-verb" something is to remove a noun that would have been created by verbing; e.g. registering adds a registration; deregistering removes it].  To "un-verb" something is to put the universe into a state as though it had never been verbed; the construct is often used to relate the impossibility of actually doing so (e.g. "what's said cannot be unsaid; what's broken cannot be unbroken").

Comment: @supercat: you're right, at least to some degree. I think that explains precisely why _un-_ with verbs was formerly nearly restricted to the semantic field I mentioned: because they were the archetypical actions which _could be undone_. You couldn't _uncook_ or _unpaint_ or _unwrite_ something, and to _unmove_ it would be just to _move_ it back. But with modern user interfaces, there are all sorts of actions that you can now undo that you couldn't in the real world, which is why I think the prefix has become more generally productive.

Comment: @ColinFine: I think the fact that more things can be undone has a lot to do with it.  Computers allow more things to be undone, but many un-actions predate computers.  A weaver who discovers a mistake sixteen rows back may either opt to cut the weft before the mistake and use a needle or comb to loosen it so it can be pulled out, or may unweave the last sixteen rows and then redo them properly.  I'm not sure what phrasing would be as clear as "unweave" to describe the action of reversing the sequence of harness pulls and weft threads in such fashion that the weft threads come free.

Comment: @Indeed. _Unweave_ is recorded from 1542, and _unknit_ much older. Entirely expected, because they are verbs of fastening/attaching or, to put it another way, actions which can genuinely be reversed.

Answer (score 7):

Very broadly, *de-* is more likely to indicate action, whereas *un-* is more likely to connote a passive status: After you *detune* your guitar, it is an *untuned* guitar.

In practice, of course, there are so many exceptions and counterexamples as to render this "rule" largely meaningless. I would guess, though, that people are somewhat more likely to follow this convention than the opposite when coining ad-hoc new words from existing roots (example: to *deselect* a check box in a computer GUI is an action, whereas *unselected* is a status that the box can have).

Answer (score 5):

Among verbs, I believe that *un-* is used to intrinsically undo something (eg, uncreating an object) whereas *de-* means to reverse its effects (eg, decompiling a program), without modifying the original item.

### Examples

- One might want to **un**say something—to take back the fact that it was said in the first place.
- People become **de**sensitized to things—their sensitivity is nullified.
- People become **de**motivated—their motivation is reversed.
- People **un**subscribe from email lists—they get rid of their subscription
- People **un**wrap things—they get rid of the original wrapping
- Arguments are **de**constructed—they are broken down and attacked; the argument itself is not destroyed.

Comment: Nice job at trying to fill in a gap in the other answers!  This is especially noteworthy because those other answers are good and accurate responses to the question, so much so that I didn't even realize there was more to say until you offered this!  I can't verify that your hypothesis is correct, but it was still worth mentioning.