# Subscribed/unsubscribed

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, past-participles

I am using a notification system where I have trouble naming a category of user.

A user can subscribe to the newsletter of the week.

- If the user set his settings, and decides to receive the newsletter of the week, he is a **Subscribed User**
- If the user set his settings, and decides Not to receive the newsletter of the week, he is an **Unsubscribed User**
- If the user did not set his settings, he is a **? User**. How do we call this category of user?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/is-there-a-general-rule-for-the-prefixation-of-un-and-de-to-words)

Comment: Undecided user, perhaps?

Comment: Yeah. That's the best option so far. Thanks Armen.

Comment: Any of *unknown, unregistered, unseen* — or simply, *new*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user would be **uncommitted** if they haven't yet told you what their preference is.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thanks Joel :) You can't imagine how long I've been looking for that word..

Comment: It helped me too! I think if some of users not be in a rush to close a topic or down vote it quickly and take a deep breath for about 5 minutes before slamming the door on new users' noses, people can find their answers and responders can find themselves useful for the main reason of this site! ;)