# How to say removing redundancy and/or duplicate entries from a list of items?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

How to say removing redundancy and/or duplicate entries from a list of items with a single word?

Comment: Is this a programming question? `short_list = unique(long_list);` is the normal idiom.

Comment: No, it's not a programming question.

Comment: That's too bad because uniquifying is good and proper programming slang for the process: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uniquify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[deduplicate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deduplicate):

> To eliminate redundant duplicate data from.

Comment: Funny that it isn’t *unduplicate*.

Comment: @tchrist I would speculate that this is because the data haven't been actively duplicated, rather there just happen to be duplicates. There is no act of duplication to reverse as an *un-* prefix would imply, perhaps.

Comment: @tchrist I appears I'm wrong about *un-* and *de-* :http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/is-there-a-general-rule-for-the-prefixation-of-un-and-de-to-words

Answer (score 3):

"Pruning" a list or database is an expression I've heard several times.

Comment: "Pruning" doesn't necessarily imply removing duplicates; it could also be used to describe, for example, removing old entries from a database.

Comment: True! It describes removing any unwanted stuff, not necessarily duplications.

On the other hand, if my job involved going through a list or database and eliminating duplicates, I'd describe it as pruning. We're getting down to context, really.