# Deselect or Unselect Checkbox?

Tags: word-choice

Which is the right usage of *unselect* or *deselect* when it comes to getting checkboxes unticked.

Will you use,

> Select/unselect the checkbox of your choice

or will you use,

> Select/deselect the checkbox of your choice

I'd like to know the more appropriate usage in this context.

Comment: Do you mean to remove the tick from an already selected box or to leave an empty box unselected? Personally I would tend to use 'deselect' for the action of removing a tick and 'leave unselected' for leaving an empty box (or a deactivated radio button) in its default state. You can use 'unselect' instead of 'deselect' for removing a tick but not, in my opinion, 'deselect' for leaving the box empty since 'deselect' implies previous selection.

Comment: @WeatherVane depends on the dialect, 'Check the box' in British English means confirm/validate, and 'unchecking the box' is not grammatical.  tick/untick would be appropriate

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18465/unselect-or-deselect